# Control the zoom when locating the current location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mapbox, react-map-gl

I am using mapbox-gl in a react app to render an interactive map. On map load, I want to center the map on the user's location while keeping the current level of zoom. Centering on the user's location works fine with geolocate.trigger(); but the map automatically zooms too close to the center. I would like to set the zoom level to 6 when the user open the web and every time he/she clicks the geoControl button.

I tried to set the max zoom to 6 as follows but I would still like to allow user to zoom in and out after clicking the button beyond 6.

```
  // const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
  //   maxZoom: 6,
  //   // minPitch: 0,
  //   // maxPitch: 85,
  // });
```

Here is a simplified version of the map component of the app. Any mapbox tips?

App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import MAP, { Marker, Popup, NavigationControl, FullscreenControl, ScaleControl, GeolocateControl } from "react-map-gl";
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

function App() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    // latitude: 0,
    // longitude: 0,
    // width: "100vw",
    // height: "100vh",
    // zoom: 6,
  });

  // const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
  //   maxZoom: 6,
  //   // minPitch: 0,
  //   // maxPitch: 85,
  // });

  const geoControlRef = useRef<mapboxgl.GeolocateControl>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Activate as soon as the control is loaded
    geoControlRef.current?.trigger();
  }, [geoControlRef.current]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <MAP
        initialViewState={viewport}
        mapboxAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/rikid/clnfluiya03tm01pjc1ncad93"
      >
        <GeolocateControl position="top-left" ref={geoControlRef} />
        <FullscreenControl position="top-left" />
        <NavigationControl position="top-left" />
        <ScaleControl />
      </MAP>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, save the map object using the Map on 'load' event. Then use the `map.easeTo()` method to navigate to the point of your desire using the 'center' property. Set the zoom level using the zoom property, like this:

```js
map.easeTo({
  center: [lng, lat],
  zoom: 6
});
```

however, keep in mind that user's location might not be close to the original viewbox of the map, which will result in some changes in the UI.

Here is a snippet for using the map's load event:

```
const [map, setMap] = useState();

function mapLoadHandler(e) {
  setMap(e.target);
}

<Map onLoad={mapLoadHandler} ...otherprops/>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more how I can implement this? I am new to React. Thank you.

Comment: I mean how to save the map object using the Map on 'load' event.

Comment: I havn't used this particular react library, but in the one i've worked with, you can pass a function to the onLoad prop of the Map component which will be called when the map has finised loading. this callback takes an `event` parameter whose target property is the map object and has all map functionalities. I'll add a code snippet to my answer to showcase.

Comment: which one do u use ?